# adding new module to carmen

Tags: carmen

i am trying to make a module in carmen through which i can interface ax 3500 motordriver..
i have written the code but i am not able to add a new module properly.... 
there is not enough documentation about adding new module to carmen if anyone has added a new module to carmen then please guide me... waiting for replies....

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the documentation in CARMEN is severly lacking. I think your best option is to contact Cyril Stachniss, and ask him directly.

:)